# Why is $\lim\limits_{h\to 0}h\cos\frac1h\stackrel{?}=0 $?

Tags: limits, trigonometry

Can someone explain why is this true? $$\lim_{h\to 0}h\cos\frac1h\stackrel{?}=0$$

$\lim_{h\rightarrow0}\cos{\frac{1}{h}}$ is undefined (limit does not exist), right? So how can the above be true?

Comment: For the limit of a product to exist, the limits of the factors need not.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Note that $\cos(x) \in [-1,1]$. Hence, we have
$$- \vert h \vert \leq h \cos(1/h) \leq \vert h \vert \,\,\,\, \forall h \neq 0$$
Now use sandwich lemma to conclude what you want.